# Consuming Spring Boot "metricsChannel" via Apache Camel/RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-camel, spring-boot, spring-messaging

Spring Boot publishes all metrics events to a message channel "metricsChannel" when a dependency on spring-messaging is present. In my project I am using Apache Camel along with RabbitMQ as the broker. Is there any way to consume these metrics messages using purely Camel and not spring integration?

I can see Apache Camel has a component SpringIntegration, however I would like to know if there is a way to directly access these messages via the RabbitMQ component or do I have to add dependency on the camel component spring-integration as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be far easier for you to implement `MetricChannel` and do whatever you want with Camel instead of trying to bridge a result with Spring integration. Look at `MessageChannelMetricWriter`, the implementation is quite straightforward.